# Python Loops and List Comprehension Connection

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

How **loops** and **list comprehension** are connected in python? Explain with **examples**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a documentation about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Loops are used for iterating through Lists, Tuples and other Iterables

```
items = [1, 3, 6]
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

```
> 1
> 3
> 6
```

List Comprehensions are used for creating new lists from another Iterable

```
items = [1, 3, 6]
double_items = [item * 2 for item in items]
print(double_items)
```

```
> [2, 6, 12]
```

You can also filter items with List Comprehensions like this

```
items = [1, 3, 6, 8]
even_items = [item for item in items if item % 2 == 0]
print(even_items)
```

```
> [6, 8]
```

Comment: "List Comprehensions are used for modifying items in lists" no, list comprehensions are for *creating new lists*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nice point, updated the answer